# Derivative of the integral $e^t/t $ from $\sqrt{x}$ to $x$

Tags: calculus

I have an integral $\frac{e^t}{t}$ from $\sqrt{x}$ to x and I have to find the derivative of this. This is for a calc II class so we haven't gone over what Ei(x) is, I'm an sure that this question is an application of FTC pt. 2.

Attempt at the solution:

1. $$\int_{\sqrt{x}}^x \frac{e^t}{t} dt$$
2. $$\int_{\sqrt{x}}^a \frac{e^t}{t} dt + \int_{a}^x \frac{e^t}{t} dt$$ for $\sqrt{x}<a<x$
3. $$\int_{a}^x \frac{e^t}{t} dt - \int_a^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{e^t}{t} dt$$
4. Differentiate both sides - $$ \frac{e^x}{x} - \frac{e^\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$$

The answer in the textbook however is $$\frac{2e^x-e^\sqrt{x}}{2x}$$

I have tried rearranging by equation by multiplying the second term by $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$ however my answer does not equal the textbook's answer. I have also graphed both my answer and the textbook's and it is clear they are not equal, due to this I am sure I made an error however I am unsure where.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: You need the Chain rule when differentiating the second integral.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$F(x)=\int_a^x \frac{e^t}{t}dt$$
Then
$$F(\sqrt{x})=\int_a^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{e^t}{t}dt$$
We have
$$\frac{d}{dx}(F(\sqrt{x}))=\frac{F'(\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
by the chain rule, and this is equal to
$$\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{2x}$$

Answer (score 0):

You should use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. By this Theorem, $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^x \frac{e^t}{t}dt=\frac{e^x}{x}\frac{d}{dx}(x)-\frac{e^\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}} \frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{x}),$$ So we have
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^x \frac{e^t}{t}dt=\frac{e^x}{x}-\frac{e^\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{2e^x-e^\sqrt{x}}{2x}.$$